# Undefined error when accessing object in angularJs

Tags: php, json, angularjs, object, laravel-5

When I am accessing following object,it throws undefined error,

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": {
        "address_info.email": [
            "The address info.email field is required."
        ]
    },
    "debug": null
}
```

console.log(data.error.message.address_info.email);

I getting error `data.error.message.address_info is undefined`,So How can I get address_info.email error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the map like syntax:

```
data.error.message["address_info.email"]
```